# Auto Mount and Backup on any usb sticks connected

Tags: backup, automounting

Hello Unix and Linux Lovers!

I have spent now about 2 days looking for a solution of my problem but couldn't find a fitting one; I like to back up files to any usb stick which is connected on a raspberry pi running raspbian.

I write here things I know, so you see what is missing:

1. Using rsync will be the best for my purpose, this should work;

   `rsync -v /home/pi/data /mnt/usb`
2. I can add the Job in crontab;

   `crontab -e`

   `0 0 * * * rsync -v /home/pi/data /mnt/usb`

This will back up my data every day (the 5 first signs are for the time Settings: Minutes Hours Days Months DayOfTheWeek, then Comes the command or script which should be executed).

3. I can manually Mount a USB Stick like this:

   `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb`

But what is missing:

- How can I mount automatically every usb stick, which is plugged in, in the Directory /mnt/usb (or /mnt/usb1, /mnt/usb2 etc)?
- How can I use rsync to sync the data in every Folder path? Do I Need a Shell script with a Loop or can I use it like this: rsync -v /home/pi/data /mnt/usb*?

Thanks in Advance for help,
Kind Regards

Comment: Is `udevd` running on `Raspbian`?

Comment: Yes, I can acces the udevd Manual, so it is accessible

Comment: if `Raspbian` is a well designed system it's probably the case but in a wider perspective availability of a particular `manpage` does not imply availability of the given tool. Anyway, if `udevd` is running you can create a rule for automatic mounting of USB storage in a given directory and with a given set of options like this: http://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/

Comment: Yes of course an existence of the manual doesn't say that the command is accessible. I just assumed that the widely spread raspbian is programmed well enough that only the needed manuals are there. Thanks, Auto mounting works with this tutorial, never thought on such a deep Level solution, just has worked. Linux is so great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was now able to do it

use the tutorial which Arkadiusz Drabczyk posted:
     http://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/

make a short script, which seeks for all Folders beginning with usbhd in the media folder and sync to them. Use "-rtuv" for Windows fat formats, they don't support POISX semantic. This all leads to this script:

```
sudo find /media -maxdepth 1 -name "usbhd*" | awk '
{
    cmd = "rsync -rtuv --exclude '\''.*'\'' /home/pi/test "$0
    system(cmd)
}' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Add a line to crontab, that the script is called regularly. Call: `crontab -e`
Add line (calls script every hr):

```
0 * * * * . /scriptpath/myscript.awk
```

And thats it.